# Why does firefox 80 start up as 98?

Tags: firefox

I have a need to use flash in firefox - this isn't supported any more, and it is in fact impossible now; this is on Linux, BTW. A solution is to run an older version of firefox* where this still works.

I have downloaded version 80, unpacked it in a local directory and run it as

```
firefox/firefox --no-remote -p someprofile
```

This, I would expect, should start firefox ver 80; however, when I check in 'Help' -> 'About Firefox', it says 98. I imagine it must be possible to actually run the version I need, but how?

(*) I know and understand the arguments for not doing this, but in this case it is necessary. Don't worry, I won't be using on a site near you; this is exclusively on my home LAN.

***Edit***

In reply Ramhound's comment: My normal firefox is version 98.0.2 (64-bit), in `/usr/bin/`, and the ver 80 is in my user home directory, `~/firefox/firefox/`

Comment: Did you turn off automatic updates for this Firefox installation?

Comment: Flash was discontinued a long time ago. Using an obsolete Firefox adds an additional layer of security problems. There's NO reason to "want" let alone "need". And unless your "home network" is completely isolated your "don't worry" argument is insanely inaccurate.

Comment: @ChanganAuto I understand what you are saying; however, that doesn't answer my question.

Comment: @DanielB No - but even if there was an automatic update immediately after I start the browser, that shouldn't affect it until I restart the browser.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n A comment is not intended as an answer. In this case I was merely trying to save you from yourself :)

Comment: So you’re saying this is the first start after unpacking. Try going to `about:support` to see what’s written there. Did you perhaps reuse an existing profile from a newer Firefox version? You shouldn’t do that.

Comment: @DanielB no, I created a new profile before starting it; I tried again, deleting the new profile and creating it, making sure to use --no-remote, but still the same.

Comment: What version of Firefox do you have installed in `/firefox/`, likewise, what directory is Firefox 80 installed to?  [Edit] your question instead of submitting a comment

Comment: @Ramhound Thanks for helping - see my edit.

Comment: @j4nd3r53n - Try providing the full path to the location Firefox 80 is installed it.  I suspect it's NOT `~/firefox/firefox/` since you indicated Firefox 98 is launching instead.  I would try `/usr/bin/firefox` instead,  It's also possible, if you did not disable the ability for Firefox 80 to update, that it might have automatically updated on you.

Comment: @Ramhound I rant it under strace, and throughout the trace it shows a remarkable number of `execve()` with the path as I expected, ie not `/usr/bin/...`

Answer (score 3):

Works for me!

I did the following:

1. Download Firefox Linux x86_64 80.0
2. Extract to `~/ff-test`
3. Create `~/ff-test-profile` dir
4. Launch it with `~/ff-test/firefox -profile ~/ff-test-profile` (not `-p`, important)

Still, it immediately updated to the latest version. So *before* launching it for the first time, you must create a policy to suppress updates.

To do this, I put in `~/ff-test/distribution/policies.json` the following:

```json
{
  "policies": {
    "DisableAppUpdate": true
  }
}
```

You can learn more about this and other policies in the [policy templates readme](https://github.com/mozilla/policy-templates/blob/master/README.md#disableappupdate).

Afterwards, you will have a Firefox instance that does not update by itself and also will not suggest updates.

You can also read up on `-profile` and other switches in the [command line options documentation](https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox/CommandLineOptions#-profile_.22profile_path.22).

Comment: Interesting - this looks promising!

Answer (score 1):

Do you also have an up-to-date version of Firefox installed? It sounds like the shell might be running the up-to-date version unintentionally. I.e., the one installed in `/usr/bin/firefox` or `/opt/firefox/firefox` or wherever.

If you're wanting to run the one you downloaded, then I'd explicitly call it within the directory.

```
$ cd path-to-firefox-80
$ ./firefox --no-remote -p someprofile
```

Notice the `./`. If you're using bash shell, then that should execute the firefox 80 version.

If that still doesn't work, then you can use `strace` to diagnose where in the process of running the command that the wrong version of firefox is getting loaded and executed.

Comment: Yeah, that's exactly what I do. Your suggestion to use strace makes sense, I'll try that.